# Distribution group members not receiving e-mail

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-group, activedirectorymembership

I'm encountering an issue within Active Directory that I'm sure has a simple solution but I just can't seem to get it working or fixed.

Basically, I have a distribution group which has Universal group scope and the members directly in this group receive e-mails sent to the DL without any issue.

Also as a member of the distribution group, I have a global security group with a few other members. The members of this security group do not receive any e-mails that are sent to the distribution list and when I look for the DL in Exchange and/or Outlook, they do not appear on the member list.

I'm sure the solution is quite simple and I'm assuming it might have something to do with the group scope, but I just cant seem to get around it and resolved.

Comment: Is the security group mail enabled?

Comment: @LisaJ, yes it is

Comment: @LisaJ it is working now, apparently it was due to the groups not being mail enabled, I just hadn't waited long enough for it to sync through to Exchange :)